# Правильно ли организована технология MVC?

Tags: php, mvc

Правильно ли я организовываю технологию `MVC`? Или мне нужно пока не поздно что-то поменять?

В `.htaccess` я прописываю, что ВСЕ запросы (например, `/news/115` или `news/edit/10`) просто адресуются на `index.php`, где инициализируется класс `Router`. Этот `Router` разбивает значение `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` на элементы, ПЕРВЫЙ из которых является названием Контроллера. Каждый Контроллер на свое усмотрение анализирует следующий элемент, который может быть как названием метода Модели, так и просто очередным индексом (товара, новости и пр.).

Итак, правильный ли такой ход событий?

Comment: И где тут MVC? ;)

Comment: @xEdelweiss,  в правом верхнем углу )))

Comment: @Deus Ваш сарказм тут не уместен. MVC - это не технология, а Design pattern.

Comment: @xEdelweiss, хорошо, изменим вопрос: Правильно ли организована технология взаимосвязи ЧПУ, Контроллеров и Моделей при создании сайта на MVC.

Comment: @Deus, вполне возможно, что правильно. Как говорится, дьявол кроется в деталях, а деталей никаких нет - вы описали стандартную схему работы большинства фреймворков. Только у них маршрутизация гибче.

Comment: @xEdelweiss, эту схему разработал я сам, поэтому и поинтересовался о ее рациональности. Есть ли толковые ресурсы, где кратко и внятно о такой маршрутизации рассказано?

Comment: @Deus, берите фреймворки и смотрите, как они работают. Начинайте с чего попроще: CodeIgniter, Kohana, Yii. Или какой-то микро-фреймворк возмите. Материалов тьма.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну теоретически правильно. Лично у меня есть файл routes.php где указаны УРЛ и соответствующие им контроллеры/экшены.

Comment: Могу ли я взглянуть на ваш файл? У вас что, прописаны все возможные комбинации УРЛ?

Comment: $route->connect('attestation/all', array('controller' => 'attestation', 'action' => 'all_exams'));
$route->connect('attestation/results/:exam_id', array('controller' => 'attestation', 'action' => 'exam_results'));
$route->connect('attestation/results/:exam_id/detail/:exam_test_id', array('controller' => 'attestation', 'action' => 'exam_results_detail'));

соответственно если адрес будет типа www.mysite.ru/attestation/result/123 - то вызовется контроллер attestation, экшн exam_result и туда передастся exam_id = 123 (в контроллере я обращаюсь к ним $this->params['exam_id'])

Comment: Как вариант, можно генерировать роутсы динамически из БД